# Cannot create scrapy tutorial project due to "system cannot find file specified" error

Tags: python, scrapy

Windows 10, Command Line Terminal, Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

New to Python & following tutorial instructions here to try and create a project called 'tutorial' -> https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Steps:

- Open terminal
- `cd c:\Anaconda\startproject`
- `c:\Anaconda\Scripts\scrapy.exe -scrapy <startproject> tutorial`

Yields this error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I leave out the <>, I get this error:

```
Error: Module 'startproject' already exists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use `<` and `>`, they are [shell redirection](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/input-output-redirection-in-the-shell) characters.
- Try starting in a different folder than your project name; `startptoject` will *create* a folder named after the project.

Comment: Renamed startproject folder to projects and it worked, thanks!